# java doesn't allow runtime-selectable-width format strings?

Tags: java, printf

I need a way to print a number as hex, as a zero-padded string of width N, where N is selectable at runtime.

This doesn't work:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%*x", 4, 0x123))
```

because evidently Java doesn't support the [C-style use of %* for runtime-selectable width format strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

Any suggestions for an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int width = 4;
String format = "%" + width + "x";
System.out.println(String.format(format, 0x123));
```

:wrysmile:

Answer (score 1):

@fd also with printf

```
int width = 4;
String format = "%" + width + "x";
System.out.printf(format, 0x123);

System.out.printf("%4x", 0x123);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use an appropriate NumberFormat.

EDIT

This is plain wrong..

Comment: Now that you're asking - no, i can't. This is plain bullshit as there is no "radix" option as i prematurely assumed. Sorry - pliiis, vote me down...

Comment: darn, I liked your approach best. :-(

Comment: Hmm: It's not builtin to standard Java, but there's http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/HexNumberFormat.html

Comment: you now definitely earned the "good samaritan" badge... you kept me from falling in deep despair.

Comment: Why don't you just delete this?